# How to change datasource during run time with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

i'm new with spring boot so i need your help.

I've got a SOAP ws which  receive a parameter in input, depending the value i need to change the default datasource.

in the picture is visible what i have on boostrap.yml

[image]

reale is the default

When the ws is invoked i test the parameter e i have to choose between
reale and virtuale

How i can do it?

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article explaining how to accomplish multiple datasources at runtime:
https://grobmeier.solutions/spring-multitenancy-switch-database-at-runtime.html

Basically you need to create each datasource as a different bean and then implement a "Routing" datasource through which all queries go through, the router chooses based on your logic which datasource is executing the query.